# Creating a SSL certificate from a request / response pair

Tags: ssl, java, tomcat

I am in possession of the following and am attempting to create an SSL certificate to be used on an Apache Tomcat server.  Usually I would generate the certificate request using keytool.  However, in this case the request / response pair was pre-generated by others.  Any suggestions on tooling and / or approach to accomplish this having the 3 pieces of data below?

Thanks!

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFnzCCBIegAwIBAgIRAKAhdt0HU4a0O4MarQ4DGZMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAw
......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIB5jCCAU8CAQAwgaUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkNBMQ8wDQYDVQQIEwZRdWViZWMxETAP
......
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXgIBAAKBgQDLfVeHiO1dCPpQYQI3X1gCVnMStitrdu7OI6iY23NowBBcwbCZ
....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Is it entirely sensible to have posted the private key?

Comment: David: the private key is probably another 6 to 20 lines longer than that; it's just the first line which isn't all that interesting.

Comment: yes, I actually just mashed the keyboard for a bit to "generate" those requests/responses/keys.  Well...  It's the morning now. Time to try this out.  Will report back shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use this bit of java http://www.comu.de/docs/tomcat_ssl/comu/ImportKey.java and something like this.  Start with your three examples in separate files with .crt, .csr and .key as the extensions.

```
CSRFILE="$1" # the certificate request file
BASE="${CSRFILE%.csr}" 
CRTFILE="$BASE.crt" # the certificate file
CRTDER="$CRTFILE.der"
KEYFILE="$BASE.key" # the private key file
KEYPKCS="$KEYFILE.pkcs8"
KEYSTORE="$BASE.keystore"


openssl x509 -in $CRTFILE -out $CRTDER -outform der
openssl pkcs8 -in $KEYFILE -out $KEYPKCS -topk8 -nocrypt -outform der
java -Dkeystore="$KEYSTORE" comu.ImportKey $KEYPKCS $CRTDER tomcat
keytool -storepasswd -new changeit -storepass "" -keystore $KEYSTORE
keytool -keypasswd -keystore $KEYSTORE -keypass "" -new changeit -storepass changeit -alias tomcat
```

The chunk of BLAH=foo stuff is get everything into variables.  the first two openssl commands convert the certificate and key into the binary format the Java stuff likes.  The java command creates a java/tomcat friendly keystore, and the two keytool commands set the password the way tomcat seems to like it out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be giving this a shot first thing in the morning.  Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Works like a charm :)